# File that exists is not found

Tags: java, filenotfoundexception

My machine has RAD 8.5 with WAS 8.5.  When I run my code I'm able to read and write to the Excel file, however when I deploy my code in the QA region (which also has RAD 8.5) I get a `No such file or directory` exception.

Initially, I tried something like this, which didn't work in QA.  The falue of `filePath` will come from the UI when the user selects an Excel file.

```
fInSt = new FileInputStream(new File(filePath));
```

So I tried this code, but it still didn't work.

```
File file = new File(filePath);
System.out.println("file.isFile())  :"+file.isFile());
System.out.println("file.isDirectory() :"+file.isDirectory());
System.out.println("file.isAbsolute() :"+file.isAbsolute());
System.out.println("file.isHidden() :"+file.isHidden());
System.out.println("file.canRead() :"+file.canRead());
System.out.println("file.canWrite() :"+file.canWrite());
System.out.println("file.canExecute() :"+file.canExecute());

fInSt = new FileInputStream(file);// below output is for file.getAbsoluteFile() but it didn't work with this either
```

I get the following error:

```
dcnFile :C:\Users\namanoha\Desktop\Restart-2007.xls
[3/14/15 0:27:18:393 EDT] 0000201b SystemOut     O file.isFile())  :false
[3/14/15 0:27:18:393 EDT] 0000201b SystemOut     O file.isDirectory() :false
[3/14/15 0:27:18:393 EDT] 0000201b SystemOut     O file.isAbsolute() :false
[3/14/15 0:27:18:393 EDT] 0000201b SystemOut     O file.isHidden() :false
[3/14/15 0:27:18:393 EDT] 0000201b SystemOut     O file.canRead() :false
[3/14/15 0:27:18:393 EDT] 0000201b SystemOut     O file.canWrite() :false
[3/14/15 0:27:18:393 EDT] 0000201b SystemOut     O file.canExecute() :false
[3/14/15 0:27:18:393 EDT] 0000201b SystemOut     O file.getAbsoluteFile() :/export/local/opt/soft/bpm85dev/WebSphere/gctbp8mbdc1_dev_node/C:/Users/namanoha/Desktop/Restart-2007.xls
[3/14/15 0:27:18:396 EDT] 0000201b SystemOut     O 2015-03-14 00:27:18,396 [WebContainer : 7] ERROR  - WebContainer : 7 com.aig.resolution.gettask.BulkRestartDCN.excelReader():Encountered Exception in excelReader/export/local/opt/soft/bpm85dev/WebSphere/gctbp8mbdc1_dev_node/C:/Users/namanoha/Desktop/Restart-2007.xls (No such file or directory)
```

Comment: `:/export/local/opt/soft/bpm85dev/WebSphere/gctbp8mbdc1_dev_node/C:/Users/namanoha/Desktop/Restart-2007.xls` doesn't look like a  valid filename, did you notice?

Comment: yes, i saw. this output i got when i gave the below code. `fInSt = new FileInputStream(file.getAbsoluteFile());`. And i changed the code to `fInSt = new FileInputStream(file);` this time i got output as C:/Users/namanoha/Desktop/Restart-2007.xls (No such file or directory).

Comment: So far you've produced zero evidence that the file exists, and eight items of evidence that say it doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds to me like you don't have that file on the QA system, or possibly it exists but is not readable by the user that runs the WAS server.

Also, that path looks like a Windows path. Is your QA environment Windows or Linux?

In any case, file paths like this should be specified by JNDI variables or in an application-specific properties file for the target environment.

Another possibility is that your user is selecting a file on the local file system and needs to upload it to the server for processing. The server cannot see the client file system. If so, you have more coding to do...

Comment: QA server is running in Linux. I need to read the file, do some process and need to write the response to the same excel file. This is wroking fine in my local machine. Do you want me to upload the file to server and start reading it ? is any other way to read the file from client machine and write the response back to it.?

Comment: @naresh vm So you need to upload the file to the server, process it and download results to the client? Am I understanding correctly?

Comment: without uploading the file to server, is there way to read the file from client machine and write the response back to it ..?

Comment: @naresh vm Only if the processing happens on the client machine, and it sounds like your processing logic is on the server. You could use Javascript or a Java applet (ugh!) on the client, but this would be unusual.

Comment: i understood. you are suggesting me to upload the file to server and process it. Then how come it is working in my local machine ..?

Comment: I assume your processing app is a J2EE web app if it is running on WAS. You are giving it a file path to process. This file path will be accessible on the local machine. Once deployed to QA, the file path will not be accessible. Try using your app from another computer - I suspect it will always process the file on your machine rather than the file on the client machine you are using.

Comment: Yes you are correct. When i tried it from different machine, am getting the same error. Can you suggest me the code to upload the file to server and download it  to the client machine.

Comment: There is plenty of example code on the Internet. Try googling on J2EE multi-part upload. It really sounds like you need some help from an experienced colleague. Good luck - I can't provide that level of help from New Zealand via SE.

Answer (score 1):

**Output the `filePath` variable, and you will see the problem.**

The contents of that variable is not a valid path.  The problem with your code is not contained in the snippet you provided.  Output the `filePath` variable and you'll see that it is not a valid path.  Then you need to track down why.